# Custom NLog Appender

Tags: c#, log4net, nlog, appender

I trying to write custom appender for logging in NLog. I saw some examlpes for log4net where should write appender which is inherit from abstract class AppenderSkeleton. Can anyone name the analog class in NLog?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

NLog analog of log4net's appenders will be target. For creating your own target, you have to inherit from `NLog.Targets.TargetWithLayout`. Also you should mark your target class with attribute `TargetAttribute`:

```
[Target("Foo")]
public class FooTarget : TargetWithLayout
{
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine(logEvent.Message);
    }
}
```

Next step is adding assembly where your class is defined to NLog extensions:

```
<nlog>
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="MyBarAssembly"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
     ...
```

And last step - registering your target (NLog will search in extensions for types market by `TargetAttribute`)

```
<target name="foo" type="Foo"/>
```